# In Google Sheets, how to achieve the “unwinding” of rows in a table that contains columns with multi-valued data

Tags: google-sheets

In Google Sheets, how can I achieve the following “unwinding” of rows in a table that contains columns with multi-valued data:

| Column A | Column B, multivalued |
| --- | --- |
| First | A,B |
| Second | C,D |

It transforms the above to:

| Column A | Column B, multivalued |
| --- | --- |
| First | A |
| First | B |
| Second | C |
| Second | D |

How can I do this easily and quickly without having to manually split the data one row by one row?

Answer (score 0):

#### My Sample Data

|  | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | First | A,B |
| **2** | Second | C,D |
| **3** | Third | E,F |
| **4** |  |  |

#### Basic Formula

The formula uses the [SPLIT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136?hl=en) function combined with [ARRAYFORMULA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275?hl=en) to return an array made up of the first column followed by the columns returned by splitting the second column.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({A1:A3, 
   SPLIT(B1:B3, ",")})
```

<sub>**Basic Formula**</sub>
[image]

#### Error Handling

Please note that [SPLIT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136?hl=en) (syntax: `SPLIT(text, delimiter)`) will return a `VALUE!` error if the `text` argument is a blank cell.  This can be avoided by wrapping it in an [IFERROR](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093304?hl=en) function.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({A1:A3, 
   IFERROR(IFERROR(SPLIT(B1:B3, ",")))})
```

<sub>**Error Handling**</sub>
[image]

#### QUERY (full columns)

Here is an example that uses complete columns and then [QUERY](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en) to return only rows where column A is populated.

```
=QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(
   {A:A, IFERROR(SPLIT(B:B, ","))}),
   "SELECT * where Col1 is not NULL")
```

<sub>**QUERY** *(full columns)*</sub>
[image]

Comment: Did this answer work for you?

Answer (score -2):

You can use the data->”split text to columns” function for this. Choose “,” as the separator in this case.